# Google App Script - Importing newest file into google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I have the below code that reads in files attached in my Gmail label

```
function importCSVGMAIL() {
  //gets first(latest) message with set label
  var threads = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName('Incremental Sales').getThreads(0,1);     
  var message = threads[0].getMessages()[0];
  var attachment = message.getAttachments()[0];

  // Is the attachment a CSV file
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var sh = ss.getSheetByName("CALLER");
    //parses content of csv to array
  attachment.setContentTypeFromExtension();  
  if (attachment.getContentType() === "text/csv") {
        var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
        var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(attachment.getDataAsString(), ",");
    // Remember to clear the content of the sheet before importing new data
    sh.clearContents().clearFormats();                                         
    //pastes array to sheet
    sh.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);
  }
}
```

The problem now is when our internal server sends data to Gmail, (I have a scheduled report for this), the label inbox shows these files in oldest - newest order. 
Then this code will parse the first item in the inbox (which is oldest.. not newest!)

Is there way to call in "newest" file by changing the code below?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The following indexing cues might be helpful:**

```
// gets first(latest) message with set label
var threads = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName('SOME LABEL').getThreads();

// Use length of the object to index last item
var first_thread = threads[0].getMessages()
var last_thread = threads[threads.length-1].getMessages();

// Only use last thread:
var last_thread_last_message = last_thread[last_thread.length-1]
var attachment = last_thread_last_message.getAttachments()[0];
```

Comment: Hey Yaakov, So I tried this code, replacing [0] [0] with [-1][-1], but it`s throwing an error message saying , TypeError: Cannot find function getMessages in object GmailThread"

Comment: + edited .getThreads to include all threads by changing to ".getthreads()"

Comment: Got it @Jason1993 I just spent a few minutes debugging and you're right. The object doesn't allow reverse indexing. I've modified to accommodate.

Answer (score 2):

Like Yaakov said... plus you may want to fetch more than one thread if you are looking for the latest one:

```
// Replace this
  var threads = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName('Incremental Sales').getThreads(0,1);

// With this
  var threads = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName('Incremental Sales').getThreads();
```